# Kotlin: sqlite database table not creating

Tags: database, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin, crash

Iam new to Kotlin. I am developing a "personality guessing" app. it was working fine but when i added SQLite database when I run it keeps crashing when i reach to activity on which SQLite is integrated. my table does not create.

[error log image here in link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bkIs.png)

Error log:
2020-06-04 13:18:10.757 16744-16744/? E/example.guessm: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-06-04 13:18:12.088 16744-16776/com.example.guessme E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2020-06-04 13:18:12.088 16744-16776/com.example.guessme E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2020-06-04 13:18:33.961 16744-16744/com.example.guessme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.guessme, PID: 16744
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.guessme/com.example.guessme.QuizActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:357)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:317)
        at com.example.guessme.DbHelper.addQuestion(DbHelper.kt:80)
        at com.example.guessme.DbHelper.addQuestions(DbHelper.kt:45)
        at com.example.guessme.DbHelper.onCreate(DbHelper.kt:35)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:412)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:341)
        at com.example.guessme.DbHelper.getAllQuestions(DbHelper.kt:93)
        at com.example.guessme.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.kt:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Code snippet of onCreate method in DbHelper class:

```
 private val DATABASE_VERSION = 2
// Database Name
private val DATABASE_NAME = "PersonalityQuiz.db"
// tasks table name
 lateinit var dbase: SQLiteDatabase

class DbHelper (context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {

override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        dbase = db
        val sql = ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT)")
        db.execSQL(sql)
        addQuestions()
        db.close()
    }
```

code snippet of addQuestions function where i insert questions to database:

```
// Adding new question
     fun addQuestion(quest: Question) {
      dbase = this.writableDatabase
            val values = ContentValues()
            values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION())
            values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA())
            values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB())
            values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC())
            // Inserting Row
            dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values)
        }
```

code snipppet for onUpgrade method:

```
override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldV: Int, newV: Int) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_QUEST")
        // Create tables again
         onCreate(db)
    }
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi. let me add some code snippets that are suspected to cause errors

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `writableDatabase` within `onCreate()`.

Either remove the `addQuestions()` call from `onCreate()`, or pass the `SQLiteDatabase` from `onCreate()` as a parameter to `addQuestions()`.

Comment: I've already tried this now new errors start to come but the problem is still there i-e table not created still and app still crashes